# retrieve and display Tamil characters from mysql database to Browser

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, unicode, character-encoding

I am using java language. I can store Tamil characters to database in the same format. But when I retrieve and display in the browser using jsp it displayed like boxes. I use the following code to save Tamil character in mysql database.

```
    Properties pr = new Properties();
    pr.put("user", "root");
    pr.put("password", "root");
    pr.put("characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
    pr.put("useUnicode", "true");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL,pr);
```

I can see the Tamil characters in database. But I can't retrieve and display in the same format. Please Help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to the top of your JSPs:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

It instructs the server to use UTF-8 to write the characters to the response. It also adds a HTTP response `Content-Type` header with a value of `text/html;charset=UTF-8`. This is quite different from a simple `<meta>` tag which is ignored by webbrowsers when the content is served over HTTP. For debugging purposes, you can see the real HTTP headers using for example Fiddler2 or Firebug.

That should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

What is the character set of your JSP pages? Make sure that it is `UTF-8`.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: This alone doesn't work. The meta tag is ignored when the content is served by HTTP.

Comment: I have used both <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> and <%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>. I think, the data retrieved from database are not in UTF-8 form.

Answer (score 0):

adarshr gave you the probable solution to your probleme, also you could read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).